# Communicating with Python shell through Node.js powered Electron application

Tags: python, node.js, input, stdin, child-process

So I'm working on this Electron application (which uses Node.js) which is basically a front-end for a python script, which functions as the backend of my application. Now I've got the following situation: I've spawned a python script which at some point prompts the user for some input by means of a simple input() function, however, when this line is executed, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
    Error: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    at PythonShell.parseError
    ...
    File ".../framework.py", line 182, in _determine_threshold
      choice = input('Do you think most of the red points are outliers? (y / n): ')
```

Now, I'm not really familiar with stdin / out, but I've managed to display some simple print statements in my console. Now my question is: is there a way to prompt the user for input, and if so, how? To be clear: I'm looking for (any) way to interact with the backend of the application. This does not have to be done with the use of the input() function. I would simply like to send the question to the front-end, and answer it there and send it back to the back-end.

I'm currently using a package called python-shell but any solution with the use of a normal spawned child process would be very welcome too!

Below both my python and Electron / Node code. Python:

```
# This is what i want prompted
choice = input('Do you think most of the red points are outliers? (y / n): ')

# This flushes previous (but not this) print statements to the console, right?
sys.stdout.flush() 

# Here I want to insert the choice of the user, from front-end, via node, to the script.
for choice in sys.stdin: 
    if choice == 'y':
    ...
```

Thanks in advance! Ps. this is my first question on StackOverflow so If anything is unclear, please let me know